# Ubuntu grep option error while executing a batch script

Tags: bash, grep

```
  #!/bin/bash
  vm1_MAC=`virsh -c qemu:///system domiflist instance-00000009 -e | grep virbr0 | awk '{print $5}'`
  vm2_MAC=`virsh -c qemu:///system domiflist instance-0000000d -e | grep -i  virbr0 | awk -e '{print $5}'`
  vm1_IP=`arp -e | grep $vm1_MAC | awk '{print $1}'`
  vm2_IP=`arp -e | grep $vm2_MAC | awk '{print $1}'`
  echo "VM1 IP Address: $vm1_IP"
  echo "VM2 IP Address: $vm2_IP"
```

The shell script was meant to display the IP addresses of my two openstack instances but I am receiving grep command option error:
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Try 'grep --help' for more information.

VM1 IP Address:

VM2 IP Address:

Is there anyone here who can assist me as I am not a bash script expert, just need to do this to get some tasks done. Thank you

Comment: The `batch-file` tag was meant for Windows .bat file.  I believe you want to use the  `BASH` tag.

Comment: I take it you are not refering to windows `batch-file` as tagged?

Comment: Check whether `vm1_MAC` and/or `vm2_MAC` contain something i.e., not empty. Print (`echo`) relevant vars and it'll be easy to figure out.

Comment: as mentioned in previous comment vm1_MAC (or 2) contain white space in the string

Answer (score 1):

This message typically happens when you try to `grep` for a string which starts with a dash.

The immediate workaround is to use `grep -e "$variable"` but really, you want to avoid the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) here.

```
#!/bin/bash
vm1_MAC=$(virsh -c qemu:///system domiflist instance-00000009 -e | awk "/virbr0/"'{print $5}')
vm2_MAC=$(virsh -c qemu:///system domiflist instance-0000000d -e | awk -e 'tolower($0) ~ /vibr0/ {print $5}')
vm1_IP=$(arp -e | awk -v mac="$vm1_MAC" '$0 ~ mac {print $1}')
vm2_IP=$(arp -e | awk -v mac="$vm2_MAC" '$0 ~ mac {print $1}')
```

Incidentally, this also demonstrates three different ways to pass a regex to Awk. Notice as well how we prefer the modern `$(command)` substitution over the dinosaur `` `backtick` `` syntax.

Comment: This assumes `$5` is correct but I suppose your original error happened because it contains something else than you thought. Adjust accordingly if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: I'm thinking there should be a way to avoid running `arp -e` twice, too...

Comment: I really appreciate your effort at @tripleee. I have been able to execute the script now after removing the -e option from the first and the second lines of the code but no output was displayed. I can confirm that the two VMs are running but still no output was displayed. Do you know what might be responsible?

Comment: I left out the prints.

Comment: Also, I meant to remark, I could find no documentation for `awk -e` but assumed it did something useful on your system.